# jqx-img-src does not work using AngularJS and JqWidgets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqwidget

I am trying to use jqx-img-src along with jqx-button (see jsfiddle 1), but I cannot get it work. However setting imgSrc property in settings works (see jsfiddle 2). But according to his JqWidgets documentation both approaches should work.

```
jsfiddle 1 : http://jsfiddle.net/bj5auao6/47/

jsfiddle 2 : http://jsfiddle.net/bj5auao6/48/
```

I have tried this on my local machine. And I get **imgSrc invalid property** when I use jqx-img-src.

Can someone please explain me, why this is happening.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: link to JqWidgets documentation [link](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/angularjs/angularjs.htm?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I should put the url in jqx-img-src in single quotes too.

```
Updated working jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bj5auao6/49/
```